# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(3x)-f(x)=x.$ If $f(8)=7$, then $f(14)$ is equal to

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Is there a general method to approach this other than $\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty}$, as it is really difficult to think about that on spot.

Comment: Probably not the expected one, but here is an approach (without any sort of limit) that works in some questions like this: Since the answer does not depend on $f$ (by the way the question is asked), any continuous function satisfying the requirements gives the answer. Substituting in the equalities, we discover that the simplest possible polynomial $f(x)=ax+b$ satisfies the conditions for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=3$. Therefore, $f(14)=\frac{14}{2}+3=10$.

Comment: How would i know if a functional equation would follow this or not

Comment: In general, it is not possible to know when it works. In order to apply this approach, you should be able to find a particular function (not necessarily a polynomial because maybe such a polynomial does not exist) that satisfies the given functional equation. But this task can be hard or even impossible.

Answer (score 14):

$$f(x)-f\big(\frac{x}{3}\big)=\frac{x}{3}.$$
Similarly, $$f\big(\frac{x}{3^n}\big)-f\big(\frac{x}{3^{n+1}}\big)=\frac{x}{3^{n+1}}.$$

Let us add this up over all $n$.

This gives $f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x}{2}$ for any $x>0$,by continuity.

Since $f(8)=7$, $f(0)$ must be $3$. Therefore, $f(14)=7+3=10$.